# What is $H^2(U(1),\mathbb Z_2)$?

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, group-cohomology, group-extensions

Let $U(1)$ denote the multiplicative group of complex numbers of modulus $1$ and $\mathbb Z_2:=\mathbb Z/(2\mathbb Z)=\left(\{0,1\},+\right)$

I know that the central group extension
$$\mathbb Z_2\overset{f}\longrightarrow U(1) \overset{g}\longrightarrow U(1)$$
with $$f:\mathbb Z_2\to U(1):n\mapsto e^{in\pi}$$ and $$g:U(1)\to U(1):z\mapsto z^2$$ is non-split, and a possible cocycle for it is

$$c: U(1)\times U(1)\to \mathbb Z_2: (e^{it_1},e^{it_1})\mapsto \begin{cases}
    0 & -\pi<t_1+t_2 \le \pi \\
    1 & \text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}$$

where $-\pi<t_1,t_2\le\pi$. This means that $H^2(U(1),\mathbb Z_2)$ is not trivial. But what is exactly $H^2(U(1),\mathbb Z_2)$? How can it be calculated?

Comment: What kind of cohomology are we talking about? Continuous? Measurable? Arbitrary?

Comment: As to classifying central extensions of $U(1)$ by $\mathbb Z_2$, a direct argument may be easier. Suppose $G$ is a topological group with a central subgroup $Z \cong \mathbb Z_2$ such that $G/Z \cong U(1)$. Topologically, $G$ is a (possibly disconnected) covering space of the circle. Consider the standard hom $F:\mathbb R \to U(1)$ with kernel $\mathbb Z$. It lifts uniquely to $\tilde F : \mathbb R \to G$. Consider $\tilde F(1) \in Z$. If $\tilde F(1) = 1$, $G \cong U(1)$. If $\tilde F(1) = 0$ then $\tilde F$ descends to a splitting map $U(1) \to G$, so $G \cong U(1) \times Z$.